# Laravel Eloquent Carbon Date only gets one result from subHours

Tags: laravel, date, time, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to get all results from a chosen date for example 10 hours ago but it will only get one result, I've only got it to work with this to get more results.

```
$sub10 = Carbon::yesterday(); // This works


$current_time = Carbon::now();
$sub10h = $current_time->subHours(10); // This doesn't

$transactionsFrom = Transaction::whereUserId($user_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $sub10h)->get();
```

Comment: Do you have the right time in `$sub10h` ?

Comment: @JhonnyWalker   "date": "2016-06-21 23:35:02" , yes the time should be right and I've tried with subHours(24) and still only one result compared to yesterday() where I get more

Comment: Out on a limb here. But try `Carbon::now(-10)` could be the `subHours` method is messing something up

Answer (score 0):

Since your granularity is *hours* not *days*, you should do this

```
$transactionsFrom = Transaction::whereUserId($user_id)->where('created_at', '>=', $sub10h->toDateTimeString())->get();
```

Note `where` instead of `whereDate` and convert Carbon instance to string using `toDateTimeString()`.

Answer (score 0):

`->subHour(10)` should work. You are using `->subHours(10)`